# Convert yuv sequence to bmp images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, yuv

I have yuv sequences and I want to convert them to bmp images. I want to save it to a folder on my computer.

I used the yuv2bmp m file in [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25563-convert-420-yuv-to-bmp) .

Although the Yuv file is only 44MB, Matlab threw a memory error.
How can I overcome this problem? Could you help me please?

Best Regards...

Comment: It's difficult to explain the memory error you're getting without more specifics. Some sample code and a sample image/file would help. The first thing I would check is how much *other* stuff you had in your workspace (i.e. other large matrices taking up all your memory).

Comment: You did not show any code, and the link you provided did not show any code. @gnovice was probably right - there's probably not enough information to help you.

Answer (score 1):

As this question doesn't have a fast answer I put here some links that may be helpful to you. But all of then refers more to implementation in C, not Matlab.

[Converting Between YUV and RGB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms893078.aspx)

[Some sample code in C](http://www.fourcc.org/source/YUV420P-OpenGL-GLSLang.c)

[That one in Delphi is pretty good](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Graphics/Colors/YUV.htm). This web site indeed is very nice web site for those that like work with image processing

[And a nice article here](http://www.fourcc.org/fccyvrgb.php#mikes_answer)

Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I've never worked with a YUV format, but [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV) says:

> Today, the term YUV is commonly used
>   in the computer industry to describe
>   file-formats that are encoded using
>   YCbCr.

If you actually *are* using a YCbCr format, and you have access to the [Image Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/), you can use the function [YCBCR2RGB](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/ycbcr2rgb.html) to convert YCbCr color values to RGB color space, then save the resulting RGB image as a bitmap using [IMWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/imwrite.html).

Answer (score 1):

Lines 20 to 39 in yuv2bmp.m read

```
    [Y,U,V]=yuvread(filename,start_frame,num_frame);%4:2:0%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

[My Ny iL]=size(Y);
[Mu Nu iu]=size(U);
[Mv Nv iv]=size(V);


for f=1:num_frame
   UU(:,:,f)= imresize(U(:,:,f),[My Ny],'nearest');
   VV(:,:,f)= imresize(V(:,:,f),[My Ny],'nearest');


    image(:,:,1) = Y(:,:,f)+1.402*(VV(:,:,f)-128);
    image(:,:,2) = Y(:,:,f)-0.34414*(UU(:,:,f)-128)-0.71414*(VV(:,:,f)-128);
    image(:,:,3) = Y(:,:,f)+1.772*(UU(:,:,f)-128);

    fname=sprintf('%s%d%s',filename(1:length(filename)-4),f,'.bmp');

    imwrite(uint8(image),fname,'bmp');
end
```

This looks like it's wasting quite a bit of memory. Unfortunately, I do not have any example yuv images, but try to modify this part of the code the following way, and check whether it still gives you the correct results:

```
for f=1:num_frame

    % read each image of the sequence separately
    [Y,U,V]=yuvread(filename,start_frame+f-1,1);%4:2:0%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    % in the following three lines, I have replaced UU with U and VV with V, and I've
    % removed all the (:,:,f)
    image(:,:,1) = Y+1.402*(V-128);
    image(:,:,2) = Y-0.34414*(U-128)-0.71414*(V-128);
    image(:,:,3) = Y+1.772*(U-128);

    fname=sprintf('%s%d%s',filename(1:length(filename)-4),f,'.bmp');

    imwrite(uint8(image),fname,'bmp');
end
```

Also, in lines 52 to 54 of yuvread.m, you can replace 'double' with 'single'. This shaves another 50% off your memory usage, and it should not make any difference to the output, since you are re-casting as uint8 in the end, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) to simply convert between YUV and BMP.

1. Download ffmpeg
2. Go to command propmt
3. Execute a command like this:

   ffmpeg.exe -s 1280x720 -i input.yuv output.bmp

   ffmpeg.exe -s 1280x720 -i input.bmp output.yuv

don't forget to change the size in the command.