# Can anybody explain about Movie function and cdata in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, cdata, movie, mov

I'm trying to figure out how to use cdata under Movie function in MATLAB. Can any expert please give me a short explanation? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can find in the MOVIE function [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/movie.html), it plays a movie, which is actually an array of frames. Frame in its turn is a single "shot", or still image, represented in MATLAB by a structure with fields cdata (matrix of pixels data) and colormap (if used).

You can create a frame from current figure with [GETFRAME](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/getframe.html) function: `F = getframe;`. `F.cdata` will be an image matrix H x W x 3, with 3rd dimension representing 3 color channels - red, green and blue. You can show it with `image(F.cdata)` command.

If `M` is a movie frames, you can show just the first frame with `image(M(1).cdata)`.

I would recommend you to play with examples on the [MOVIE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/movie.html) and [GETFRAME](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/getframe.html) help pages to have a better understanding.

Comment: Hi yuk. Thanks for your explanation. It was quite clear. But I got a bit difficulty over here. How do I show the content of cdata so that I can do further manipulation?

Comment: Is `image` or `imshow` not enough for you? Or explain what do you mean "show the content"?

Comment: okay. Im trying to use movie function to read a yuv video clip and store the data. Do you think the following piece of program will work?for k=1:nFrames mov(l).cdata=loadFileYuv(...) end the loadFileYuv function can be found over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887494/how-to-extract-y-u-and-v-components-from-a-given-yuv-file-using-matlab-each-com

Comment: I've used `loadFileYuv` from your other previous questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614441/how-to-extract-frames-from-yuv-420-video-clip-and-store-them-as-different-images. If you run `mov = loadFileYuv(file, 176, 144, 1:nFrames);` you will get variable that you can use directly in `movie` function. To access individual frames `imshow(mov(i).cdata)`.

Comment: Thanks yuk! That really works! Now I'm working on how to separate the y,u,v components in a single frame. Thanks again!

Comment: Check my answer to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887494/how-to-extract-y-u-and-v-components-from-a-given-yuv-file-using-matlab-each-com. Also if an answer is helpful to you please consider upvoting and don't forget to accept the best answer.